# Converting tidyeval arguments to string

Tags: r, stringr, tidyeval, r-glue

I have a simple function in R with `...` using tidyeval. Is is possible to change these into a string?

```
simple_paste <- function(...){
  my_vars <- enquos(...)
  paste(..., sep = "_x_")
}
```

`simple_paste(hello, world)`

As an output, I would like to get `"hello_x_world"`. I could also consider using the `glue` function or `str_c` instead of `paste`, although I'm not sure that would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the quosure to character and then `paste`

```
simple_paste <- function(...) {
  purrr::map_chr(enquos(...), rlang::as_label) %>% 
          paste(collapse="_x_")
   }
simple_paste(hello, world)
#[1] "hello_x_world"
```

---

Or another option is to `eval`uate an expression

```
simple_paste <- function(...)  eval(expr(paste(!!! enquos(...), sep="_x_")))[-1]
simple_paste(hello, world)
#[1] "hello_x_world"
```

if we need `.csv` at the end

```
simple_paste <- function(...)  eval(expr(paste0(paste(!!! enquos(...), sep="_x_"), ".csv")))[-1]
simple_paste(hello, world)
#[1] "hello_x_world.csv"
```

Comment: thanks! taking this a step further do you have advice on ending the string with `.csv`? -- `hello_x_world.csv`

Comment: I recommend using `as_string()` instead of `quo_name()` which is likely to be deprecated. If you really want the quo-name behaviour, use the more explicit `as_label()`. But `as_string()` looks right here. See `?as_label`.